# How to use Futura font in latex?

Tags: fonts

I'm on Mac using the standard package that is available. I've tried and tried. but it's not happening

could somebody explain what needs to be done to have Futura font displayed in latex?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) since we do not have access to your computer, it might be an idea to post the sample code you have tried. Do you even have the font? Are you using a latex engine that can access a system font?

Comment: @daleif I'm new to the latex all I have is The MacTeX distribution  and I don't even know if it contains the font or not

Comment: You said you tried and tried, exactly what did you do? You are not giving us much to wort with here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I gather your computer runs MacOSX, possibly (likely?) MacOSX 10.12 "Sierra". If so, `Futura Medium` may be installed by default in the file `/Library/Fonts/Futura.ttc`. By the way, [Futura](https://www.linotype.com/1559658/futura-complete-family-pack-product.html) is a fairly large family of fonts, with 6 weights -- Light, Book, Medium, Heavy, Bold, and Extra Bold -- in the "regular" category and 4 more weights -- Light, Medium, Bold, and Extra Bold -- in the "condensed" category. For each weight, there's both an upright and an oblique (aka slanted) font shape.

Assuming you have access to just the system selection of Futura weight/shape/(non)condensed combinations, the following program -- to be run under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX -- should give you access to both the upright and the oblique font shape of `Futura Medium`.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = xelatex % or: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Futura Medium}[ItalicFont={Futura Medium Italic}]

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\itshape
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

---

*Update*, September 2022: I wrote the answer shown above in March 2017, on a MacBook Air that used MacOSX 10.12 "Sierra" and MacTeX2016. At the time, the font file `Futura.ttc` was located in the folder `/Library/Fonts/`. In contrast, under MacOS 10.15 "Monterey", the file `Futura.ttc` is located at `/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/`. Good news: the little demo program shown above works just fine under MacTeX2022.

Comment: trying what you said , I get an error !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:28: Fatal fo
ntspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
! "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

Comment: @DannyNelson - "trying what you said" -- actually, you're not. The error message says it all: You've been trying to compile the file using pdfLaTeX. That cannot and will not work, as I wrote in my answer as well. You need to compile it under either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: so basically my package of latex can't do jt, I should get one of the two you mentioned right?

Comment: @DannyNelson - I have no idea what you mean by "package". For the document in my answer to compile, it must -- repeat: *must* -- be run under either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Did I not state this clearly enough in my answer and in the comment above? The document is definitely not going to compile successfully under pdfLaTeX.

Comment: ok, I just downloaded and installed XeLaTeX. could you please tell me how should I compiled now?

Comment: @DannyNelson - I have no idea what you're doing. You say you have MacTeX2016, right? (I do too, by the way.) If so, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX should all have been installed right away and should have been available to you all along. Which front-end editor do you use? TeXworks? TeXshop? Something else?

Comment: I though It's not installed, I don't know) I've installed this: http://www.tug.org/mactex/ and if I should use something else please let me know, I'd rather use the package that most people do. and I use TeXshop for wiring and compiling

Comment: @DannyNelson - Ok, thanks for letting on that you use TeXshop. In TeXshop, do you notice the second rectangular "button" from the left, in the zone above the type area? It probably says "LaTeX". Click on the drop-down box symbol next to it and select either "LuaLaTeX" or "XeLaTeX". Then click on the "Typeset" button to the left...

Comment: wow, I'm an idiot) all done. you're phenomenal man! I can't thank you enough!! thank yoooooooooooouuu!!)

Comment: @DannyNelson - Glad you're on your way! Do try to familiarize yourself a bit with the capabilities of TeXshop -- it'll come in very handy, I can guarantee it. :-)