# How could I change the Beamer class default font?

Tags: beamer, fonts

How could I change the Beamer class default font in order to use Futura or Gill Sans or any other font? Do I have to use Xelatex? This is a MWE :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{\textbf{A title}}
\subtitle{A subtitle}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{A title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360448/how-to-use-futura-font-in-latex for Futura (requires XeLaTeX)

Comment: There is no need to write `\usetheme{default}` as this is done by default.  You can always choose a font theme with `\usefonttheme{...}`

Comment: I don't understand. I can't manage to use any other fonts than Palatino. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futura requires XeLaTeX; see [How to use Futura font in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360448/)

Gill Sans can be loaded with the `gillius` or `gillius2` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{gillius}

\title{A title}
\subtitle{A subtitle}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A title}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A frame}

  Frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can find many fonts in the LaTeX Font Catalogue at URL https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/

Beamer uses the `\sfdefault` family. If you want to use another family, you may need to redefine the `\familydefault`.  For example, to use the French Cursive font for your presentation, you can do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{frcursive}
\edef\familydefault{\rmdefault}


\title{A title}
\subtitle{A subtitle}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A title}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A frame}

  Frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]