# Changing font in beamer class default

Tags: beamer, fonts

I want/have to change my font in my beamer class to [Nunito](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/nunito?lang=de)

For an article, the following works perfectly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{nunito}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Regular}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection*{Italic}
\textit{\lipsum[2]}

\subsection*{Bold}
\textbf{\lipsum[2]}

\subsection*{Medium}
{\fontseries{medium}\selectfont\lipsum[5]}

\subsection*{Extra Light}
{\fontseries{el}\selectfont\lipsum[5]}

\subsection*{Light}
{\fontseries{l}\selectfont\lipsum[5]}

\subsection*{Semi Bold}
{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont\lipsum[6]}

\subsection*{Extra Bold}
{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont\lipsum[6]}

\subsection*{Black}
{\fontseries{ub}\selectfont\lipsum[6]}

\subsection*{Default Numbers}
1234567890

\subsection*{Tabular Numbers}
{\nunitotabular 1234567890}

%%NOT AVAILABLE
%%\subsection*{Proportional Numbers}
%%{\nunitoproportional 1234567890}

\subsection*{Superscripts}
X{\sufigures 1234567890}

\end{document}
```

However, my minimal example

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%%%nunito font as in pptx
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{nunito}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

does not work. I assumed this from [user94293](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516912/how-could-i-change-the-beamer-class-default-font) solution here. Also, his second solution works, not with the example-font he is using, but with Nunito somehow:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nunito}
\edef\familydefault{\rmdefault}


\title{A title}
\subtitle{A subtitle}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A title}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A frame}

  Frame content
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I now have a work-around, which I clearly do not unsterdand. Any explanations? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, beamer uses sans serif font. The `nunito` package however changes the serif font (even if the font itself does not have serifs, so using the term in quotation marks for the rest of the answer).

You can either use the `serif` font theme to tell beamer to use the "serif" font instead:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{nunito}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or you could use the `mainfont` option of `nunito`, which change the font used in the document to the "serif" font:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mainfont]{nunito}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is an answer I perfectly understand and I should have realised earlier. Thank you very much

Comment: @MichaelFischer You're welcome! Have fun with beamer!